# pycaffe 'solver.step' fails to train using Adam

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to train a model using pycaffe. I use Adam Optimizer
The forward and backward codes work fine:

```
solver.net.forward()
solver.net.backward()
```

However on the update step (`solver.update()`) it fails with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AdamSolver' object has no attribute 'update'
F1102 12:14:25.689537 24420 benchmark.cpp:18] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (10 vs. 0) invalid device ordinal
```

When I try the `solver.step(1)` I gives me:

```
solver.step(1) failed to work with the following error: 
F1101 19:28:43.213888  5038 benchmark.cpp:30] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (71 vs. 0)  operation not supported
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I suspect that there is an installation issue, actually I had few test cases that fails in my runtest, is that related and what I would need to fix if I need to rebuild?

**EDIT 1:**
I fixed all the issues I have in the runtest, but still having the same problem.

Comment: what tests have failed? you need to provide more information. Currently it seems like your GPU does not support CUDA version expected by caffe.

Comment: Here are the tests that fails, and I fixed that .. now trying to rebuild and find if it will fix this issue or not https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073514/caffe-runtest-fails/47074039#47074039

Comment: still fails .. all the test cases running successfully

Comment: do you have more than one GPU on your machine? are both errors still occurring?

Comment: I use `caffe.set_device(0)` so i believe its not multiple GPU issue and nah its only one GPU anyway

Comment: and yes I have both errors occuring, but for the `solver.update`, I have an additional error printed: `F1102 12:14:25.689537 24420 benchmark.cpp:18] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (10 vs. 0)  invalid device ordinal`

Answer (score 1):

Place`caffe.set_mode_gpu()` and `caffe.set_device(0)` before the `caffe.get_solver(solver_path)`  solved the issue.