# Caffe runtest fails

Tags: caffe

After successfully building caffe, I make runtest and it fails in ImageDataLayer, DBTest, DataTransformTest, HDF5OutputLayerTest and some solvers.

Is there a missing step in the building/linking to specific paths?

Here is the part of the test cases that fails (some at the end are removed to reduce the question body length:

```
[  FAILED  ] 349 tests, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] NetUpgradeTest.TestUpgradeV1LayerType
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/0.TestAllInOneNetTrain, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/0.TestAllInOneNetDeploy, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/0.TestAllInOneNetVal, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/1.TestAllInOneNetTrain, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/1.TestAllInOneNetVal, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/1.TestAllInOneNetDeploy, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/2.TestAllInOneNetVal, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/2.TestAllInOneNetTrain, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/2.TestAllInOneNetDeploy, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/3.TestAllInOneNetVal, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/3.TestAllInOneNetTrain, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NetTest/3.TestAllInOneNetDeploy, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/0.TestSpace, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/0.TestReshape, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/0.TestShuffle, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/0.TestResize, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/0.TestRead, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/1.TestRead, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/1.TestReshape, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/1.TestSpace, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/1.TestResize, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/1.TestShuffle, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/2.TestReshape, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/2.TestShuffle, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/2.TestSpace, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/2.TestResize, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/2.TestRead, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/3.TestRead, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/3.TestReshape, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/3.TestSpace, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/3.TestResize, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] ImageDataLayerTest/3.TestShuffle, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] HDF5OutputLayerTest/0.TestForward, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] HDF5OutputLayerTest/1.TestForward, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] HDF5OutputLayerTest/2.TestForward, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] HDF5OutputLayerTest/3.TestForward, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/0.TestGetDB, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLevelDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/0.TestWrite, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLevelDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/0.TestKeyValue, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLevelDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/0.TestNext, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLevelDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/0.TestSeekToFirst, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLevelDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/1.TestSeekToFirst, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLMDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/1.TestKeyValue, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLMDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/1.TestGetDB, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLMDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/1.TestNext, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLMDB
[  FAILED  ] DBTest/1.TestWrite, where TypeParam = caffe::TypeLMDB
[  FAILED  ] DataTransformTest/0.TestMeanFile, where TypeParam = float
[  FAILED  ] DataTransformTest/1.TestMeanFile, where TypeParam = double
[  FAILED  ] LayerFactoryTest/0.TestCreateLayer, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] LayerFactoryTest/1.TestCreateLayer, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] LayerFactoryTest/2.TestCreateLayer, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] LayerFactoryTest/3.TestCreateLayer, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReshapeLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTrainLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestSkipLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTrainLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReshapeLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestSkipLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTestLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/0.TestReadCropTestLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTrainLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTestLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestSkipLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReshapeLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReshapeLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTestLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTrainLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/1.TestSkipLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestSkipLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReshapeLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTrainLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestSkipLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTestLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReshapeLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTestLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/2.TestReadCropTrainLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTrainLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestSkipLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTestLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTestLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestSkipLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTrainSequenceUnseededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReshapeLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTrainLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReshapeLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLevelDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] DataLayerTest/3.TestReadCropTrainSequenceSeededLMDB, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecayMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecayMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/1.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecayMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/2.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecayMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] SGDSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/1.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/2.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestAdaGradLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaGradSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecayMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdateLROneHundredth, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/3.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/3.TestNesterovLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] NesterovSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/0.TestAdaDeltaLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/1.TestAdaDeltaLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/1.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/1.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithMomentumMultiIter, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/1.TestAdaDeltaLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/3.TestAdaDeltaLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/3.TestAdaDeltaLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/3.TestAdaDeltaLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdaDeltaSolverTest/3.TestAdaDeltaLeastSquaresUpdateWithHalfMomentum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestAdamLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestAdamLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestAdamLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/0.TestAdamLeastSquaresUpdate, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/3.TestAdamLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/3.TestAdamLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/3.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/3.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] AdamSolverTest/3.TestAdamLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithRmsDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/0.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithRmsDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/1.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithRmsDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccumShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithWeightDecay, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestSnapshot, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestSnapshotShare, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/2.TestRMSPropLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverything, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[  FAILED  ] RMSPropSolverTest/3.TestLeastSquaresUpdateWithEverythingAccum, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<double>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer fixed it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762296/871418

`export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

or add it to

`sudo vim /etc/default/locale`